# Display names of column of recursive list as tree

Tags: r

Is there a (built'in/easy) way to **recursively display the `names` of a interlinked list as a tree?** (with possibly an output similar to the `tree` shell command. )

For instance with list X, with two column A and B, A consiting in two subcolumn a1 and a2

```
nametree(x)
X
├── A
│   ├── a1
│   └── a2
└── B
```

`names(X)` would just display `[1] "A" "B"`

Comment: What's the structure of your dataframe?

Comment: It's rather complex, why I would prefer a generic tool.
In a nutshell, it's an object in which I store, some data (in a col), metadata (in an other col), and various clusterisations in other cols(each of them structured in dataframe by functions i'm using)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. A data.frame does not have subcolumns. It is two dimensional, i.e. rows, and columns. Maybe you are talking about lists? In any case the str(x) will print out the structure of the object at hand.

Comment: Indeed you are right, it's list. (it's just some of leaves that are dataframe), I'll just correct question

Comment: @AdrieanKhisbe make a toy (small) example object of said data structure and paste it's structure here using `dput( exampleobject )`

Comment: Well then give @Dr. Mike's suggestion a try. `mylist <- list(A = list(a1 = 1, a2 = 2), B = "b")`; `str(mylist)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
nametree <- function(X, prefix = "")
  if( is.list(X) )
    for( i in seq_along(X) ) { 
      cat( prefix, names(X)[i], "\n", sep="" )
      nametree(X[[i]], paste0(prefix, "  "))
    }
X <- list(X = list( A = list( a1=1:10, a2=1:10 ), B = 1:10 ))
nametree(X)
# X
#   A
#     a1
#     a2
#   B
```

Displaying the tree structure with branches rather than spaces is slightly trickier:

```
nametree <- function(X, prefix1 = "", prefix2 = "", prefix3 = "", prefix4 = "")
  if( is.list(X) )
    for( i in seq_along(X) ) { 
      cat( if(i<length(X)) prefix1 else prefix3, names(X)[i], "\n", sep="" )
      prefix <- if( i<length(X) ) prefix2 else prefix4
      nametree(
        X[[i]], 
        paste0(prefix, "├──"),
        paste0(prefix, "│  "),
        paste0(prefix, "└──"),
        paste0(prefix, "   ")
      )
    }
nametree(X)
# X
# +--A
# ¦  +--a1
# ¦  +--a2
# +--B
# +--C
#    +--a
#    +--b
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple example:

```
> mylist <- list(A=data.frame(A1=1:3,A2=4:6),B=7:9)
> out <- lapply(mylist,names)
$A
[1] "A1" "A2"

$B
NULL
```

This assumes you only have dataframes one level below the list...so it's not recursive per se, but it sounds like this is similar to your data structure.

DrMike and Henrik's suggestion to use `str(mylist)` will be recursive and is, in fact, able to control both how deep into the structure and the display of the output.

SimonO101's example of recursion:

```
> df <- data.frame( A = runif(3) , B = runif(3) )
> ll <- list( A = df , B = list( C = df , D = df ) , E = 1 )
> str(ll)
List of 3
 $ A:'data.frame':      3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ A: num [1:3] 0.948 0.356 0.467
  ..$ B: num [1:3] 0.2319 0.7574 0.0312
 $ B:List of 2
  ..$ C:'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ A: num [1:3] 0.948 0.356 0.467
  .. ..$ B: num [1:3] 0.2319 0.7574 0.0312
  ..$ D:'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ A: num [1:3] 0.948 0.356 0.467
  .. ..$ B: num [1:3] 0.2319 0.7574 0.0312
 $ E: num 1
```

Some examples of output:

```
> str(mylist)
List of 2
 $ A:'data.frame':      3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ A1: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ A2: int [1:3] 4 5 6
 $ B: int [1:3] 7 8 9

> str(mylist, give.attr=FALSE, give.length=FALSE, give.head=FALSE, vec.len=0, 
indent.str="|", comp.str="----")
List of 2
|----A:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
| ..$ A1:NULL ...
| ..$ A2:NULL ...
|----B:NULL ...
```

Comment: This time you best me to it by 10 seconds! :-)

Comment: Although, now do this with multiply nested list elements, e.g... `df <- data.frame( A = runif(3) , B = runif(3) ); ll <- list( A = df , B = list( C = df , D = df ) , E = 1 )`

Comment: @SimonO101 That's why `str` is the way to go.

Comment: Nice, I have never used arguments in `str` before. FYI, another option in the case I gave is `rapply`, e.g. `rapply( ll , names , how = "list" )`, but not nearly as nice formatting as `str`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the data.tree package. For example:

```
x <- list( A = list( a1 = list(data = 1:10), b1 = list(data = 1:100 )), B = list(data = c(1, 3, 5) ))
library(data.tree)
xtree <- FromListSimple(x, nodeName = "X")
xtree
```

This prints out:

```
   levelName
1 X         
2  ¦--A     
3  ¦   ¦--a1
4  ¦   °--b1
5  °--B
```

Or you can convert the data into a printable format:

```
print(xtree, maxData = function(node) if (is.null(node$data)) 0 else max(node$data))
```

Which shows:

```
   levelName maxData
1 X                0
2  ¦--A            0
3  ¦   ¦--a1      10
4  ¦   °--b1     100
5  °--B            5
```

Finally, to show the names of a node:

```
names(xtree$children)
```

This prints:

```
[1] "A" "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with, see function definition at the bottom.

sample data:

```r
# a short list
l1 <- list(a = factor("1"), b = c(u = 3, v = 4), d= list(x=5, y =6), e= 8, f = 9)
# a longer list
l2 <- replicate(100, l1, simplify = F)
```

default way of printing a short list:

```r
print_list(l1)
#> $a
#>  [1] 1
#>  Levels: 1 
#> $b
#>  u v 
#>  3 4  
#> $d
#>   $x
#>    [1] 5 
#>   $y
#>    [1] 6 
#> $e
#>  [1] 8 
#> $f
#>  [1] 9
```

restrict to first 3 items when named :

```r
print_list(l1,n_named = 3)
#> $a
#>  [1] 1
#>  Levels: 1 
#> $b
#>  u v 
#>  3 4  
#> $d
#>   $x
#>    [1] 5 
#>   $y
#>    [1] 6 
#> # + 2 named items
```

pass parameters to `print()`

```r
print_list(l1, quote = TRUE)
#> $a
#>  [1] "1"
#>  Levels: "1" 
#> $b
#>  u v 
#>  3 4  
#> $d
#>   $x
#>    [1] 5 
#>   $y
#>    [1] 6 
#> $e
#>  [1] 8 
#> $f
#>  [1] 9
```

use `str()` rather than `print()` on non list items:

```r
print_list(l1, fun = str)
#> $a
#>   Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 
#> $b
#>   Named num [1:2] 3 4
#>   - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "u" "v" 
#> $d
#>   $x
#>     num 5 
#>   $y
#>     num 6 
#> $e
#>   num 8 
#> $f
#>   num 9
```

use invisible rather than print to display only names:

```r
print_list(l1, fun = invisible)
#> $a
#>   
#> $b
#>   
#> $d
#>   $x
#>     
#>   $y
#>     
#> $e
#>   
#> $f
#>
```

print long list with restrictions:

```r
print_list(l2,n_named = 3, n_unnamed = 2)
#> [[1]]
#>   $a
#>    [1] 1
#>    Levels: 1 
#>   $b
#>    u v 
#>    3 4  
#>   $d
#>     $x
#>      [1] 5 
#>     $y
#>      [1] 6 
#>   # + 2 named items
#> [[2]]
#>   $a
#>    [1] 1
#>    Levels: 1 
#>   $b
#>    u v 
#>    3 4  
#>   $d
#>     $x
#>      [1] 5 
#>     $y
#>      [1] 6 
#>   # + 2 named items
#> # + 98 items
```

**function code**

```r
#' print list nicely
#'
#' @param l list to print
#' @param n_named max number of named items to display if list/sublist contains only named items
#' @param n_unnamed max number of items to display if list/sublist contains unnamed items 
#' @param fun function to use to print non list items
#' @param ... additional arguments passed to fun
#'
#' @return unchanged input
#' @export
print_list <- function(l,
                       n_named = 20, 
                       n_unnamed = 6, 
                       fun = print,
                       ...){
  dots <- list(...)
  fun0 <- function(l) do.call(fun, c(list(l),dots))
  print_list0(l, nm = NULL, i = NULL, indent = -2,
              n_named = n_named, n_unnamed = n_unnamed , fun = fun0)
}

print_list0 <- function(l, nm = NULL, i = NULL, indent=-2, 
                       n_named = 20, 
                       n_unnamed = 6, 
                       fun){
  if(!is.null(nm)){
    if(nm!=""){ 
      cat(strrep(" ", indent), "$", nm,"\n",sep="")
    } else {
      cat(strrep(" ", indent), "[[", i,"]]\n",sep="")
    }
  }

  if(is.data.frame(l) || !is.list(l)){
    output <- capture.output(fun(l))
    output <- paste(strrep(" ", indent), output, collapse="\n")
    cat(output,"\n")
  } else {
    nm = allNames(l)
    named <- all(nm != "")
    if(named && length(l) > n_named){
      n_unshowed <- length(l) - n_named
      l  <- l[seq_len(n_named)]
      nm <- nm[seq_len(n_named)]
      Map(print_list0, l, nm, i = seq_along(l), indent=indent+2,
          n_named = n_named, n_unnamed = n_unnamed,
          fun = replicate(length(l), fun))
      cat(strrep(" ", indent+2), "# + ", n_unshowed, " named items\n",sep="")
    } else if(length(l) > n_unnamed){
      n_unshowed <- length(l) - n_unnamed
      l  <- l[seq_len(n_unnamed)]
      nm <- nm[seq_len(n_unnamed)]
      Map(print_list0, l, nm, i = seq_along(l), indent=indent+2,
          n_named = n_named, n_unnamed = n_unnamed,
          fun = replicate(length(l), fun))
      cat(strrep(" ", indent+2), "# + ", n_unshowed, " items\n",sep="")
    } else {
      Map(print_list0, l, nm, i = seq_along(l), indent=indent+2,
          n_named = n_named, n_unnamed = n_unnamed,
          fun = replicate(length(l), fun))
    }
  }
  invisible(l)
}
```